# How to open Facebook Album from Appcelerator Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I know how to make an intent in android, you open a specific album of a Facebook page. I tried opening the page, but I can't open the album page.

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent ({
         action: Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
         data: 'fb: // page / {id}'
}); Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity (intent);
```

I put it this way: 'fb://album/131980240302966?owner=#116121531888837'

But it does not work, this is the page I try to access ...

https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.131980240302966.29820.116121531888837&type=3

Can you tell me what is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no supported way to open any Facebook url

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'd like to open an URL scheme? You should use [Ti.Platform.openURL](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Platform-method-openURL) for that.

Here's a list of Facebook URL schemes you could try:
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook